# Pytest - How to override fixture parameter list from command line?

Tags: python, testing, pytest

Consider the following fixture

```
@pytest.fixture(params=['current', 'legacy'])
def baseline(request):
    return request.param
```

I wonder if there is a way to launch pytest so it overrides the fixture parameter list with the value(s) given on the command line, i.e.:

```
pytest --baseline legacy tests/
```

The above should effectively result in params=['legacy'].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go with dynamic parametrization via [`Metafunc.parametrize`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#_pytest.python.Metafunc.parametrize):

```
# conftest.py
import pytest


@pytest.fixture
def baseline(request):
    return request.param


def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption('--baseline', action='append', default=[],
        help='baseline (one or more possible)')


def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
    default_opts = ['current', 'legacy']
    baseline_opts = metafunc.config.getoption('baseline') or default_opts
    if 'baseline' in metafunc.fixturenames:
        metafunc.parametrize('baseline', baseline_opts, indirect=True)
```

Usage without parameters yields two default tests:

```
$ pytest test_spam.py -sv
...
test_spam.py::test_eggs[current] PASSED
test_spam.py::test_eggs[legacy] PASSED
```

Passing `--baseline` overwrites the defaults:

```
$ pytest test_spam.py -sv --baseline=foo --baseline=bar --baseline=baz
...
test_spam.py::test_eggs[foo] PASSED
test_spam.py::test_eggs[bar] PASSED
test_spam.py::test_eggs[baz] PASSED
```

You can also implement "always-in-use" defaults, so additional params are always added to them:

```
def pytest_addoption(parser):
    parser.addoption('--baseline', action='append', default=['current', 'legacy'],
        help='baseline (one or more possible)')


def pytest_generate_tests(metafunc):
    baseline_opts = metafunc.config.getoption('baseline')
    if 'baseline' in metafunc.fixturenames and baseline_opts:
        metafunc.parametrize('baseline', baseline_opts, indirect=True)
```

Now the test invocation will always include `current` and `legacy` params:

```
$ pytest test_spam.py -sv --baseline=foo --baseline=bar --baseline=baz
...
test_spam.py::test_eggs[current] PASSED
test_spam.py::test_eggs[legacy] PASSED
test_spam.py::test_eggs[foo] PASSED
test_spam.py::test_eggs[bar] PASSED
test_spam.py::test_eggs[baz] PASSED
```

Comment: I appreciate your thorough response and properly idiomatic code. Much obliged.

Comment: Glad I could help!

Comment: There should be a comma in place of the dot in the default list in the second example, but StackOverflow requires at least six characters to edit. :-/

Comment: Is there no way to access what is passed to `params` argument of the fixture? Seems confusing to have default values reside in the conftest.py rather than within the decorator call. My ideal situation would be default `params` is defined with the fixture and then can be overridden with command line arguments with `pytest_addoption` and `pytest_generate_tests`